# Check if the character exists in the collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a CSV file with zip codes. Some cities have only one zip code whereas some have multiple zip codes.

```
istat;municipality;region;province_abbreviation;province;zip_code_check;zip_code;lat;lng
60006;Anagni;Lazio;FR;Frosinone;"03012";"03012";41.74393633;13.15452041
67002;Ancarano;Abruzzo;TE;Teramo;64010;64010;42.83680898;13.74139609
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60121;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60122;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60123;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60124;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60125;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60126;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60127;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60128;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60129;43.61675973;13.51887537
42002;Ancona;Marche;AN;Ancona;60121-60131;60131;43.61675973;13.51887537
```

I am getting these in the `$collection` I want to extract the row which has `-` in the `zip_code_check` column. I tried `$collection->where('zip_code_check', 'like'. '%-%')` but it did not work. Is there any way I can get rows when the column `zip_code_check` has `-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used str_contains but it returned a boolean instead of a filtered row. Here is how I fixed my problem.

```
$filter = $collection->filter(function($value, $key) {
if (str_contains($value['zip_code_check'], '-')) {
        return $value;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use (" ") instead of (' '), like this: ('zip_code_check', 'like', "%-%")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using where + like, another possible solution:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$filteredCollection = $collection->filter(function($item){
    return Str::contains($item->zip_code_check, '-');
});
```